# PL SQL: how do I get more than one value in the same cell? listagg, ok. But

Tags: reporting-services, plsql, birt

I'm new to stackoverflow so please excuse me if I'm not asking properly.

I just received a ticket asking to modify a report.

The actual situation is that when an employee is enrolled into a training that has more than one instructor employees' records get duplicate as many times as the number of instructors.

e.g. as follow

---

Stud_id |    ins_fname   | ins_lname

---

001    |        ugo       |    red

---

001       |     marco       |   green

instead it should be

---

Stud_id   | ins_fname  | ins_lname

---

001    |    ugo, marco | red, green

I know that there is LISTAGG to solve this issue, however is not working as it should.

I guess because the stud_id values has being pulled from a nested table, so the report I am working on looks something like this

SELECT
col_1,
col_2,
ins_fname,
ins_lname,
col_n+1...n,
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
  stud.stud_id,
  col_n+1...n,
  FROM table
) tableName,
tableName2,
tableName3,

WHERE 1=1

Is there any chance that this is impacting the LISTAGG functionalities?

The error I'm getting is the following

The column 'I.MI' (which follows the columns I'm trying to listagg out) is invalid in the select list because the GROUP BY clause or an aggregation function does not contain it: line 26 col 7 (at pos 1010)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.util.SQLExceptionHelper.wrapSQLException(SQLExceptionHelper.java:44)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.util.SQLExceptionHelper.wrap(SQLExceptionHelper.java:25)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.command.CommandProcessor.process(CommandProcessor.java:165)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.servlet.ServletCommandSink.handleRequest(ServletCommandSink.java:176)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.servlet.ServletCommandSink.doPost(ServletCommandSink.java:150)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.

I know that is not the clearest question but still I'd strongly appreciate any support.

The compiler I'm using is Plateau Report Designer which is something built on top of BIRT linked to ORACLE db

Thank you all and happy new year

Answer (score 1):

I think that I understood your issue and it's related to grouping stuff!

I took the time to recreate your request and this is what I could do using LiveSQL from Oracle

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hr0w91uigngd7wg5895ov7vc7

If you don't have access to Oracle, you could create a free account, but the following is the code I wrote.

```
DROP TABLE training_instructor;
DROP TABLE training_enroll;
DROP TABLE employee;
DROP TABLE instructor;
DROP TABLE training;

CREATE TABLE employee(
  employee_id    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
 ,employee_name  VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE instructor(
  instructor_id    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
 ,instructor_name  VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE training(
  training_id    NUMBER   PRIMARY KEY
 ,training_name   VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE training_instructor(
  training_id    NUMBER
 ,instructor_id  NUMBER
 ,PRIMARY KEY(training_id, instructor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE training_enroll(
  training_id    NUMBER
 ,employee_id    NUMBER
 ,PRIMARY KEY(training_id, employee_id)
);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1,  'Employee 1');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(2,  'Employee 2');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(3,  'Employee 3');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(4,  'Employee 4');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(5,  'Employee 5');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(6,  'Employee 6');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(7,  'Employee 7');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(8,  'Employee 8');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(9,  'Employee 9');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(10, 'Employee 10');
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO instructor VALUES(1, 'Instructor 1');
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES(2, 'Instructor 2');
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES(3, 'Instructor 3');
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES(4, 'Instructor 4');
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES(5, 'Instructor 5');
COMMIT;


INSERT INTO training VALUES(1, 'Training 1');
INSERT INTO training VALUES(2, 'Training 2');
INSERT INTO training VALUES(3, 'Training 3');
INSERT INTO training VALUES(4, 'Training 4');
INSERT INTO training VALUES(5, 'Training 5');
COMMIT;


INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(3, 3);
INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(3, 5);
INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(4, 2);
INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(4, 4);
INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(5, 4);
INSERT INTO training_instructor VALUES(5, 5);
COMMIT;


INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(2, 6);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(2, 8);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(2, 10);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(2, 5);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(2, 4);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(3, 3);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(3, 5);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(5, 10);
INSERT INTO training_enroll VALUES(5, 6);
COMMIT;
/
-- The final query
SELECT e.employee_id 
      ,e.employee_name 
      ,t.training_name 
      ,LISTAGG(i.instructor_name, ' | ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY i.instructor_name) instructor_list 
  FROM employee e 
       JOIN training_enroll te 
         ON e.employee_id = te.employee_id 
       JOIN training t 
         ON te.training_id = t.training_id 
       JOIN training_instructor ti 
         ON te.training_id = ti.training_id 
       JOIN instructor i 
         ON ti.instructor_id = i.instructor_id 
GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.employee_name, t.training_name 
ORDER BY e.employee_id, t.training_name
```